# get v-id-xx value for scoped css on Vue Single File Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When adding elements via pure js on Vue Single File Component, the added elements don't have v-id-xx attribute for scoped css.

How can I get THE component's v-id-hash value by pure js?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scoped-style data ID is added to the component instance as:

```js
this.$options._scopeId // returns something like 'data-v-763db97b'
```

This way you could add it as attribute using:

```js
somElement.setAttribute(this.$options._scopeId, "");
```

Here's a [**CodeSandbox demo** showing an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl99xj39qw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue).

Answer (score 0):

In a Vue 3 directive, we can get the component's scope ID using the `binding` parameter available in directive lifecycle hooks.

Example:

In mounted hooks:

```js
mounted(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  console.log("scope_id", binding.instance.$options.__scopeId);
  span.setAttribute(binding.instance.$options.__scopeId, "");
  el.appendChild(span);
},
```

In the DOM, the element we will have the scope ID attached. Now we don’t need to use `:deep()` or `/deep/` anymore for the directive-created element.

```html
<span data-v-0fb92912=""></span>
```