# How to apply css style after createElement in vue component?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, components

```
<template>
  <div id="body">
    <button type="button" @click="create">Create</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      create () {
        let e = document.createElement('input');
        e.classList.add('input-test');
        e.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        e.setAttribute('value', 'test');
        document.getElementById('body').appendChild(e);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style scoped>
.input-test {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

I tried this code. But input-test style wasn't applied.
Why can't apply to element?
It works when I remove scoped at style tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by deep selectors
[deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

If you look how vue handles style scoping you will see that all elements get a identifier for the scope which will be added to your scoped css. Any new created element won't get transpiled by vue so it doesn't get the needed scoping identifier.

If you only want show an element when the button is clicked you should add it to the dom and only show it on click with the `v-if` [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926050/5899698

In the resulting element of `createElement` you can add the scoped css identifier using:

```
e.setAttribute(this.$options._scopeId, '');
```

Comment: I've already solved it, but your answer was also very helpful. Thanks a lot.